# Checkbox values in to array

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

```
<?php
 $query_o_meno = "SELECT meno FROM uctovnictvo GROUP BY meno ORDER BY meno";     
 $result_meno = mysql_query($query_o_meno) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<form method="post">

<?php

 echo "<strong>Meno:</strong>";
 echo "<br />";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_meno)){
 echo '<input type="checkbox" name=" option_meno[] " value="XXX" />' . $row['meno'];
 echo "<br />";
 }

?>
<input type="submit" name="Filtrovat" value="Filtrovat" />
</form>
```

Hello could u please help me to solve:

- SOLVED - Instead of XXX in value="**XXX**" i wanna have value of $row['meno']
- TO DO - Checked values I wanna insert in to array

Thank you

Comment: I see that for now I have -2 points. You can ask me if you dont understand it or make it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo "<input type='checkbox' name='option_meno[]' value='".$row['meno']."' />" . $row['meno'];`

Does that put the value in the 'value'?

Comment: Yes this is workng just fine. Now I need to insert values in to array.